# How do I optimize nextjs dev mode build performance?

Tags: performance, webpack, next.js, build

I have a small nextjs application that relies on several internal and external libraries. While a production build has great performance, dev builds are atrociously slow. When I make a change to a page component which triggers a rebuild, I see messages of this sort in the console:

```
event - compiled client and server successfully in 15.5s (2267 modules)
event - compiled client and server successfully (2279 modules)
```

I've gathered that this is a very large number of modules. But what can I do about it? How do I find more information as to the source of these modules so that I can eliminate them or optimize further?

What is considered an "acceptable" number of modules that would not result in rebuild times approaching 60s?

Answer (score 4):

I ran into the same problem and after a long search I found out that it was caused by loading `@material-ui/icons` as they are imported from an internal package installed in the `node_modules` folder whereas in production mode, they are imported directly from the code.

> **Development environment :**
> Development bundles can contain the full library which can lead to slower startup times. This is especially noticeable if you import from @material-ui/icons. Startup times can be approximately 6x slower than without named imports from the top-level API.

I followed this [guide](https://v4.mui.com/guides/minimizing-bundle-size/#option-2) which offers two solutions :

1. Using path imports to avoid pulling in unused modules.
2. Adding a babel plugin to automatically rename named imports to default imports (**more recommanded since it provides the best user experience and developer experience**)

After using babel and renaming named imports to default, I went from 11.3 seconds compile time to 2.9